# VB6 RegFree Com one click deployment

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I made a vb6 reg free com one click deployment project
I added manifest file after publish and change content to use my vb name Green.exe instead of vb.net project name. also changed properties to content and copy if newer. When I install it on client, vb6 program cant start `cause of not registered ocx. it means reg free com is not right`.
we created lots of ocx which main vb6 program will using. Here is manifest file I created:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly xsi:schemaLocation="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1                 assembly.adaptive.xsd" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:co.v2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v2" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:co.v1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1">
      <asmv1:assemblyIdentity name="Green.exe" version="1.0.0.1" publicKeyToken="0000000000000000" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="x86" type="win32" />
  <application />

  <trustInfo>
    <security>
      <applicationRequestMinimum>
        <PermissionSet Unrestricted="true" ID="Custom" SameSite="site" />
        <defaultAssemblyRequest permissionSetReference="Custom" />
      </applicationRequestMinimum>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <!--
          UAC Manifest Options
          If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level     replace the 
          requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following.

        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator"     uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable"     uiAccess="false" />

         If you want to utilize File and Registry Virtualization for     backward 
         compatibility then delete the requestedExecutionLevel node.
    -->
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <dependency>
    <dependentOS>
      <osVersionInfo>
        <os majorVersion="10" minorVersion="1" buildNumber="2600"     servicePackMajor="0" />
      </osVersionInfo>
    </dependentOS>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly dependencyType="preRequisite"     allowDelayedBinding="true">
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Windows.CommonLanguageRuntime"     version="4.0.30319.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>


  <file name="Green.exe" size="7184384">
    <hash>
      <dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-    com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
      </dsig:Transforms>
      <dsig:DigestMethod     Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
      <dsig:DigestValue>rqeYDzIVrIY9m/pVlyFdJ6tFpAc=</dsig:DigestValue>
    </hash>
  </file>
  <file name="Green.ReportControl.v15.0.1.ocx" size="1370104">
    <hash>
      <dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-    com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
      </dsig:Transforms>
      <dsig:DigestMethod     Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
      <dsig:DigestValue>DR4oqg8TvRGA7901DvJ8kwQZt48=</dsig:DigestValue>
    </hash>
  </file>
  <file name="GreenACITrans.ocx" size="937984">
    <hash>
      <dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-    com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
      </dsig:Transforms>
      <dsig:DigestMethod     Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
      <dsig:DigestValue>LbPTQBKEGlaE2nD02Lle+jPz1gU=</dsig:DigestValue>
    </hash>
  </file>
  <file name="GreenBackUpRestore.ocx" size="217088">
    <hash>
      <dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-    com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
      </dsig:Transforms>
      <dsig:DigestMethod     Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
      <dsig:DigestValue>EALTeLxgFCOKv256oJyr7T0eRg8=</dsig:DigestValue>
    </hash>
  </file>

</asmv1:assembly>
```

Edited: I fixed it. there was a component which it cant be register and i didnt know. i placed it in setup package and now its working. 
using this link steps:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa697429(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: It has a lot of stuff that doesn't have to be there, not enough of the stuff that needs to be there.  None of the *required* `<comClass>` elements are present.  Docs for it [are here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Vb.net made this manifest for my project

Comment: For VB6 reg-free manifests you need a tool like [UMMM](https://github.com/wqweto/UMMM). You cannot "hack" it with VB.Net like you tried.

Comment: Thanks guys. it is not a hack. it is from microsoft link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa697429(v=vs.80).aspx   . one of my ocx was from prev developer. i didnt know it makes a problem and shouldnt be in manifest. now it works as the link i placed said!

Comment: Please can you add your fix as an answer so it is clear this question has a solution instead of an update to the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys. it is not a hack. it is from microsoft link:
 [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa697429(v=vs.80).aspx) . one of my ocx was from prev developer. i didnt know it makes a problem and shouldnt be in manifest. now it works as the link i placed said!